# Symfony 6 | Serializer component to deserialize nested JSON

Tags: php, json, symfony, serialization

I am using the serializer component from Symfony.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

I want to convert the following response to a php class object.

```
{
    "data": {
        "uuid": "d1830cc0-f35a-11e8-8ca1-5254003b69f1",
        "name": "***",
        "last_name": "Admin",
        "fullname": "***",
        "email": "***@***.com",
        "created_at": {
            "time24": "16:13",
            "time": "04:13",
            "date": "2018-11-28",
            "datetime": "2018-11-28 16:13:22",
            "meta": {
                "meridiem": "pm",
                "day": 28,
                "month": 11,
                "year": 2018,
                "month_name": "November"
            }
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "time24": "16:13",
            "time": "04:13",
            "date": "2018-11-28",
            "datetime": "2018-11-28 16:13:22",
            "meta": {
                "meridiem": "pm",
                "day": 28,
                "month": 11,
                "year": 2018,
                "month_name": "November"
            }
        },
        "relationships": {
            "role": {
                "uuid": "d14ee40e-f35a-11e8-bbfc-5254003b69f1",
                "name": "admin",
                "label": "Admin",
                "public": true,
                "created_at": {
                    "time24": "16:13",
                    "time": "04:13",
                    "date": "2018-11-28",
                    "datetime": "2018-11-28 16:13:21",
                    "meta": {
                        "meridiem": "pm",
                        "day": 28,
                        "month": 11,
                        "year": 2018,
                        "month_name": "November"
                    }
                },
                "updated_at": {
                    "time24": "16:13",
                    "time": "04:13",
                    "date": "2018-11-28",
                    "datetime": "2018-11-28 16:13:21",
                    "meta": {
                        "meridiem": "pm",
                        "day": 28,
                        "month": 11,
                        "year": 2018,
                        "month_name": "November"
                    }
                },
                "relationships": {
                    "permissions": [
                        {
                            "name": "admin",
                            "label": "Admin"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I was trying to do is to use this website:

https://jacobdekeizer.github.io/json-to-php-generator/#/

It gave me a long series of classes, to summarize, the root object looks like this:

```
class Response
{
    public Data $data;

    public function getData(): Data
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function setData(Data $data): self
    {
        $this->data = $data;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to deserialize it like this:

```
/** @var Response $response  */ 
        $response = $this->serializer->deserialize($response->getContent(), Response::class, 'json');
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Failed to denormalize attribute "data" value for class "App\Http\Booking\Models\Response": Expected argument of type "App\Http\Booking\Models\Data", "array" given at property path "data".
```

My serialize object looks like this:

```
class MySerializer {
    public static function getSerializer()
    {
        $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer()];

        return new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    }
}
```